# Check if given *args and **kwargs satisfy given function signature (Signature.bind() in python2)

Tags: python, python-2.7

Given an arbitrary function definition:

```
def f(a, b, *args, kw_a=None, kw_b=123, **kwargs):
    ...
```

Is there an easy way of checking whether the given `args` and `kwargs` will satisfy the following call:

```
f(*args, **kwargs)
```

without actually calling the function at hand?

I know that in python3.3 and up there's `inspect.Signature.bind()`. Is there anything easier in python2.7, than using `inspect.getargspec()` and parsing the returned `ArgSpec` tuple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading a suggestion from Vaultah's comment, I found that there indeed is a backport of `inspect.signature` to python2.

It's called [funcsigs](https://pypi.org/project/funcsigs/#description).